How do I stop unwanted apps getting installed on my Moto g23?
I have a Moto g23. Ever since I (absent mindedly) poked about some of the pre-installed apps, every few weeks or so I'll find a new game or something is automatically installed.



Is there a way to turn this off? (But still get the OS security updates.)
I only ever immediately uninstall them when I notice them without even considering if I might actually like the game or whatever it is.
(My wife has the same model and this never happens to her. I suspect because she didn't go poking around the phone and accidentally switching things on.)

Have you tried to uninstall or disable the "MotoApps" app?

@Robert - It's a core app. It can't be uninstalled.

But it may be possible to disable it via adb (pm uninstall ...), have you tried that?

@Robert - I didn't even know there was a command prompt on this thing.

Have you checked if there are some settings inside MotoApps itself, or whatever the app the notification came from (looks like something related to game)?

@AndrewT. - I have, but alas, nothing is obvious as the key. I didn't even realise I had turned it on until I found a game had been installed.

https://www.reddit.com/r/motorola/comments/1802l72/motorola_phone_keeps_installing_unwanted_apps/?rdt=61430
